# Function loop True or False

Tags: python, while-loop, return, function

I am now learning functions in python. I came across an exercise that asks me to write a script that will tell the user that the student is in a class or not. Here is the result that the script should present:

```
Welcome to the student checker!
Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit): [student1]
No, that student is not in the class.
Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit): [student2]
Yes, that student is enrolled in the class!
Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit): q
Goodbye!
```

I have written a script that fulfills the requirements. Here is the script:

```
print "Welcome to the student checker!"

students = ['Andreas', 'Martina', 'Maria']

while True:
    name_student = raw_input("Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit): ")

    if name_student == 'q':
        print "Goodbye!"
        break

    if name_student in students:
        print "Yes, {} is enrolled in the class!".format(name_student)

    elif name_student not in students:
        print "No, {} is not in the class.".format(name_student)
```

But the exercise states that there should be a function that returns True if the student is present, and False if not.

Could anybody enlighten me on how can I change my script to fulfill the requirement of adding a function that returns True if the student is present, and False if not?

Thanks in advance!! Peace!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
print "Welcome to the student checker!"

students = ['Andreas', 'Martina', 'Maria']

def is_present(name_student):
    if name_student in students:
        print "Yes, {} is enrolled in the class!".format(name_student)
        return True

    elif name_student not in students:
        print "No, {} is not in the class.".format(name_student)
        return False

while True:
    name_student = raw_input("Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit): ")

    if name_student == 'q':
        print "Goodbye!"
        break

    is_present(name_student)
```

Wrap the logic into a function, so it can return a value, and call it each time your infinite loop iterates.

@edit
@barak manos is right, I updated the code

Comment: I would put the `raw_input` line outside the function, and pass the input to the function.

Comment: Ahhh..Now I see where and how should I use function. Thanks guys!!! You're all the best!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to convert the student test into a function:

```
def student_present(student):
    return student in ['Andreas', 'Martina', 'Maria']

print "Welcome to the student checker!"

while True:
    name_student = raw_input("Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit): ")

    if name_student == 'q':
        print "Goodbye!"
        break

    if student_present(name_student):
        print "Yes, {} is enrolled in the class!".format(name_student)
    else:
        print "No, {} is not in the class.".format(name_student)
```

Note `student in [xxxxxx]` automatically gives you a boolean result which can be returned directly. There is no need to explicitly return `True` and `False`.

Another point to consider, what happens if `martina` is entered? Using the current code it would state `not in class`. If you changed the function as follows, it would also accept this:

```
def student_present(student):
    return student.lower() in ['andreas', 'martina', 'maria']
```

Comment: Thanks Martin!!! Your explanation is really clear and understandable!!! Cheers to that!! I will be needing a lot of advice from you and the expert in this community during my programming journey!! Thanks all :)